# Method in abstract class that references the .class object

Tags: java, android, gson

I'm using the GSON library in Android, and one of the more common tasks I'm doing is to serialize/unserialize objects.

Serialize is pretty easy:

```
public String serialize() {
        // Serialize this class into a JSON string using GSON
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
```

Unserialize has to reference the .class object like so:

```
static public AbstractGSON create(String serializedData) {
        // Use GSON to instantiate this class using the JSON representation of the state
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(serializedData, AbstractGSON.class);
    }
```

If I create a class that extends AbstractGSON, how can I get that method to create an instance of the new class? Or is it not possible via inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the class as a parameter to the method:

```
public <T> T deserialize(final String data, final Class<T> className)
```

Then use it to deserialize your data:

```
return gson.fromJson(data, className);
```

And you can call it like this for example inside a class that extends your abstract class :

```
User user = super.deserialize(data, User.class);
```

Hope it helps.